# Are bigger AB wheels better?

Tags: abdominals

I just bought a ab wheel and have been doing it for a few time by now but I noticed that a lot of videos on YouTube with ripped guys showing how to use the ab wheel they use much bigger wheels than mine.

Are bigger wheels better than smaller wheels ? If not why their size varies and which size is better for me? I wonder that the ripped guys use bigger ones for a reason right?

My AB wheel is about this size :

[image]

And I've seen guys using ones about this size :

[image]

Comment: Compensation? My impulse is that the size of the wheel would only influence how low to the ground you'd get. A larger wheel would mean that, at the end of pushing out, you're using more of your abs instead of having to rely on shoulder muscle. I suppose larger wheels would weigh more, but wheels being what they are mechanically, that shouldn't change things much.

Comment: I don't know. Should I buy a bigger one then?

Comment: I honestly don't think it will make that much of a difference. Just to clarify, are you walking about a larger diameter wheel, or one with a thicker width? Are we talking taller tires or fatter ones?

Comment: @SeanDuggan See my edit

Comment: Hmm... I can write my suppositions, but I can't give you anything authoritative. Do you feel like that would still be useful to you?

Comment: Sure, better than nothing

Comment: Considering just the wheels; a larger wheel is likely to have a larger moment of inertia. This would make a larger (in size and weight) wheel harder to rotate (so would require more energy) at the same speed as a smaller (in size and weight) wheel.

Comment: Smaller wheel is harder. One might experiment with hand placement, wide or small. But one has to get a longer bar to try this. Narrow grip is harder, because of hands being further out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anecdotally I've used smaller ones and bigger ones and never noticed much of a difference. The bigger and fancier ones, honestly, are generally just about marketing. Instead of buying the [$9 one](http://amzn.to/1ZeEQvB) at Target, you can buy the [$59 version](http://amzn.to/1ZeEOEf) that has a ripped model on the front and some thermoplastic spokes in an Ⓐ anarchy symbol.

I've noticed that higher hand positions make it easier in fact. You can see this if yourself if you do [ring rollouts](http://www.fitstream.com/exercises/ring-rollout-a162). From that linked website:

> The closer you are to being parallel to the ground and at full stretch
>   the more difficult the exercise becomes.

So the higher your hands are, the easier it is.

Comment: Nice! Thanks...I guess i'll stick to my small ab wheel then...

Answer (score 2):

**Size won't have much of an impact**. The only difference is the height between your hands and the floor, which is not even relevent to toning up your core.

If there is a difference, you could argue that using the smaller wheels is harder. Just imagine a VERY BIG wheel : your hand being high above the floor results in a tilt of your body, which would lead to a easier exercice (less weight, like you could experience with a pushup).

That being said, the difference is very small, and you wouldn't feel that one is better. The only thing that could differ from one wheel to another is how "well-oiled" it is. A wheel that rolls very smoothly is harder to keep in place. You have to counter this absence of resistance by yourself, thus involving your muscles more.

Answer (score 1):

I belive that the resistence is different smaller wheels = harder due to increased range of motion. Comparable to regular vs. Inclean push-ups

Comment: please support with evidence? Comparison is completely different and doesn't describe any significant difference. Also how is there an increased range of motion? It's also INCLINE* push-ups. Again, the resistance would be the same...so how is it different?

Answer (score -1):

Heres my thinking on how a smaller wheel might effect the core somewhat differently than the large wheel   Compare the motion of the wheel  to a pull up on a bar  If you do a shoulder width pull up it will enhance the lats to that width  Now do an extended width pull up  it will enhance the latteral muscles to that width  Therefore I believe the bigger wheel is giving the upper chest and lats more of a lateral stretch  matching that stretch to the abs taking in the obliques more than a smaller wheel  My advice is to use both